# Need of Integration testing

Tags: testing, junit, integration, eclipse-pde

We have Eclipse UI in the frontend and have a non Java based backend.

We generally write Unit tests separately for both frontend and backend.
Also we write PDE tests which runs Eclipse UI against a dummy backend.

My question is do we need to have integration tests which test end to end.

One reason i might see these integration tests are useful are when i upgrade my frontend /backend i can run end to end tests and i find defects.

I know these kind of questions are dependent on particular scenario.
But would like to what is the general and best practice followed by all here.

cheers,
Saurav

Answer (score 3):

As you say, the best approach is dependant on the application. However, in general it is a good idea to have a suite of integration tests that can test your application end-to-end, to pick up any issues that may occur when you upgrade only one layer of the application without taking those changes into account in another layer. This sounds like it would be definitely worthwhile in your case, given that you have system components written in different languages, which naturally creates more chance of issues arising due added complexity around the component interfaces.

One thing to be aware of when writing end-to-end integration tests (which some would call system tests) is that they tend to be quite fragile when compared to unit tests, which is a combination of a number of factors, including:

- They require multiple components to be available for the tests, and for the communication between these components to be configured correctly.
- They exercise more code than a unit test, and therefore there are more things that can go wrong that can cause them to fail.
- They often involve asynchronous communication, which is more difficult to write tests for than synchronous communication.
- They often require complex backend data setup before you can drive tests through the entire application.

Because of this fragility, I would advise trying to write as *few* tests as possible that go through the whole stack - the focus should be on covering as much functionality as possible in the fewest tests possible, with a bias towards your most important functional use-cases. A good strategy to get started would be:

- Pick one key use-case (which ideally touches as many components in the application as possible), and work on getting an end-to-end test for this (even just having this single test will bring a lot of value). Focus on making this test as realistic as possible (i.e. use a production-like deployment), as reliable as possible, and as automated as possible (ideally it should run as part of continuous integration). Even just having this single test brings a lot of value.
- Build out tests for other use-cases one test at a time, again focusing on your most important use-cases at first.

This approach will help to ensure that your end-to-end tests are of high quality, which is vital for their long-term health and usefulness. Too many times I have seen people try to introduce a comprehensive suite of such tests to an application, but ultimately fail because the tests are fragile & unreliable, people lose faith in them, don't run or maintain them, and eventually they forget they even had the tests in the first place.

Good luck and have fun!